# Search in the database

Tags: c#, sql, database, t-sql

This Messages form display table with these informations (ID,FROM,TO,TITLE,MESSAGE).

I am trying to search for all the messages send to a certain user . user will enter his name in the `Search_textBox` then it will filter the table to keep only messages to this user.

```
private void Search_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText = "Select * from MessagesTable where To =" + Search_textBox.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", Search_textBox.Text);

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
      
      
    }
```

**I get this error :**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'To'.'
```

Comment: so try and copy out the text you think that comment text has and try and run it inside your db

Comment: can you output to the information console (or debug message) the contents of the cmd variable after all initializations?

Comment: what is `search_name` ? is it a column in the table ? The query doesn't look right

Comment: @Squirrel I have updated the cod. search_name is the text_box data that user will enter.

Comment: Do you know how to debug your code? Set a breakpoint, copy the query and check the syntax.

Comment: Does MessagesTable have column Name ?

Comment: no "Name" is the input from user in the textBox. then ill use it to display all the massages from this user .

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022

Comment: This question is turning into a debugging session. This is not the original code and error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is Correct

```
private void Search_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from MessagesTable where  [To]= @To";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", Search_textBox.Text);

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What does the "search_name" parameter contains? The Message? The Column Name?

Your query is

```
Select * from MessagesTable where " + search_name + " = @From"
```

Then you specifies the "search_name" as a parameter for the @From...
So I believe your input was "Name" and your query is looked like this now:

```
Select * from MessagesTable where Name = 'Name';
```

You do not have any Name column in this specified table as you described.

Comment: I have updated the cod. search_name is the text_box data that user will enter. its "@Form" colum data

Comment: Do you follow this pattern of writing a query? I think you should double check:

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column_Name = 'Something'

Comment: still gives me same error .

Comment: I would propose that we stop just guessing any answers that might be correct or not and the OP stops refusing to debug like everyone else does. If you have a problem in your code, you will debug it. No need to ask questions in Stackoverflow before having done this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it as follows. Of course, if I understand correctly, that you want to search in the messages field by the input you get from the user.

```
private void Search_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from MessagesTable where  MESSAGE = @From";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", search_name);

    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
  
  
}
```

Comment: I have updated the  code could you check it .I think I've clarified what I am trying to do .

Comment: Could you please tell us why you still refuse to debug your code? Do you think ignoring this important question and to let other people do your work is the correct way? I could understand if you didn't know that it's possible to debug or how to do it, but I even give you a link to a documentation, so you don't even have to search for it.

Comment: Not ignoring .I have already made the debug and same issue appear in this line `   adapter.Fill(dataSet);`

Comment: Ok, which is the entire SQL query that you find in cmd.CommandText?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.SqlClient.dll but was not handled in user code
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'To'.

Comment: This is no query, this is an error message. Which is the query in cmd.CommandText BEFORE trying to execute it?

Comment: where is "@To" in cmd.CommandText ?

Comment: your Code is correct but dont use   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", Search_textBox.Text);

Answer (score 0):

Try with To, because "To" - keyword SQL:

```
cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText = "Select * from MessagesTable where [To] =" + Search_textBox.Text;
```